# Printing a multiline d.text in GRASS-GIS when using Python grass-session

Tags: grass-gis

Here is what I'm trying to do, but the text remain printed in one line. What is wrong?

```
from grass_session import Session
from grass.script import run_command

with Session(gisdb="path to mygisdb", location="myL72",
             create_opts="EPSG:31370") as sess:

    cptxt = "- first line \n"
    cptxt += "- second line \n"

    run_command('d.text',
                text=cptxt,
                color='grey',
                rotation=0,
                linespacing=1.8,
                at=[2, 45],
                align='ll',
                size=2.5
                )
```

But the result is `- first line - second line`.

Any idea?

Comment: Try to use `\r\n` or `\r`. I'm not sure if it works. Or `d.text` may not support linefeed (`\n`).

Comment: I'm in a linux environment, normally `\n` should be enough. I've tried your suggestion, but it does not solve the problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `d.text` may not support linefeed (`\n`). I think that, because for example `v.label` supports linefeed and this is clearly stated in [docs](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.label.html). I think it would have been stated if `d.text` supported `\n`.

Comment: I'm adapting a bash script that was using version 6.4 and `\n` was supported. I haven't checked if it is still the case in a bash script, but in python it seems that you are right. I found a workaround using an input file instead.

Comment: The best way is to check the source code at https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/tree/master/display/d.text and propose, as needed, a code improvement.

Comment: .. or open an issue here: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues

Comment: Thanks markusN I've introduced a feature request https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/1233

Answer (score 2):

I've found another way to do it, but I don't find it very elegant. `d.text` accepts a string or a file. In this second case it works as expected.

```
cptxt = "- first line \n"
cptxt += "- second line \n"

myfile = 'input_text.txt'

with open(myfile, "w") as ftxt:
    ftxt.write(cptxt)

run_command('d.text',
            input=myfile
            )
```

I'm still looking if using a string directly is anyway possible.